# Sampling from columns of ys stacked over values of x in R (visual provided)

Tags: r, statistics, sampling, resampling

## Background

I have a two variables called **x** and **y** (please see R code below the picture). When I `plot(x, y)`, I obtain the top-row plot (see below). `y` values are stacked over the top of each `x` value.

## Question

I am wondering WHY when I sample from `y` values that are separately stacked over the top of each `x` value (e.g., y-values stacked over the top of x value of "0"), I get some sampled `y` values that are outside their range of their mother sample!? (***please see the bottom-row table to see this***).

[image]

## HERE IS MY R CODE:

```
 #############  Input Values ###################
                      each.sub.pop.n = 150; 
                      sub.pop.means = 20:10; 
                      predict.range = 0:10; 
                      sub.pop.sd = .75;
                      n.sample = 2;
 #############################################
  par( mar = c(2, 4.1, 2.1, 2.1) )

  m = matrix( c(1, 2), nrow = 2, ncol = 1 ); layout(m)

  Vec.rnorm <- Vectorize(function(n, mean, sd) rnorm(n, mean, sd), 'mean')

  y <- c( Vec.rnorm(each.sub.pop.n, sub.pop.means, sub.pop.sd) )

  x <- rep(predict.range, each = each.sub.pop.n)

  plot(x, y)


  ## Unsuccessfull Sampling ##
  x <- rep(predict.range, each = n.sample)

  y <- sample(y , length(x), replace = TRUE)

  plot(x, y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your sample is not conditional on x in your unsuccessful sampling piece. In the below, I split the y data by x and then sampled two cases from each. The result seems to work.

```
sample <- lapply(split(y, x), function(z) sample(z, n.sample, replace = TRUE))
sample <- data.frame(y = unlist(sample), 
                     x = as.numeric(rep(names(sample), each = n.sample)))
plot(sample$x, sample$y)
```

[image]

Comment: I actually think it just comes from the `y <- sample(y , length(x), replace = TRUE)` part, because you're sampling `length(x)`, or 20, values from the entire y vector with replacement, rather than sampling conditional on x (i.e., within each strata). Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually, though, if you did keep it as a matrix you could sample with the apply function, looping through the columns. Something like `apply(y, 2, function(x) sample(x, n.sample, replace = TRUE))`.

Comment: Daniel, something not working right! change `predict.range = 0:10`; to `predict.range = `10:0` and you'll see the sample goes in the reverse direction!

Comment: I had an error in how I was defining the `x` variable in the sample data frame. Check out the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stratified sampling implemented in the `sampling` package with the `strata` function:

```
  par( mar = c(2, 4.1, 2.1, 2.1) )
  m = matrix( c(1, 2), nrow = 2, ncol = 1 ); layout(m)
  Vec.rnorm <- Vectorize(function(n, mean, sd) rnorm(n, mean, sd), 'mean')
  y <- c( Vec.rnorm(each.sub.pop.n, sub.pop.means, sub.pop.sd) )
  x <- rep(predict.range, each = each.sub.pop.n)
  plot(x, y)

  library(sampling)
  df <- data.frame(x,y)
  set.seed(123)
  stratif_sampl <- strata(df,"x",rep(2,11))
  idx <- stratif_sampl$ID_unit
  plot(x[idx], y[idx])
```

[image]